# Click event doesn't fire for table rows added dynamically

Tags: jquery, html-table, click, row, addition

I have an empty table to which I'm adding rows via jQuery using:

```
$('#table > tbody:last').append('<tr id="' + symbol.Code1 + '"><td>' + symbol.Code1 + '</td><td>' + symbol.Code2+ '</td><td>' + symbol.Code3+ '</td></tr>');
```

Everything is OK but when I implement:

```
$("#table tr").click(function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

nothing happens.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) you can use **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to bind the click event for dynamically added elements. **The way you are binding with click will apply on existing element** but not elements which are added later.

```
$(document).on("click", "#table tr", function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

You can limit the scope for `on` by giving closest parent selector either by id or by class of parent.

```
$('.ParentElementClass').on("click", "#table tr", function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

**[Delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't recommend to use `document` or `body` as the parent selector, since it makes event reaction slower. It is better to use the closest static parent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I spent hrs scratching my head about similar problem

Comment: FINALLY, someone answered the question I was looking for. I had exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 10):

You have to use the `.on` method

```
$("#table").on('click','tr',function(e) { 
    alert($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the accepted one as it locks to the closest *static* parent as @VisioN has mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You add rows dynamically after you have bound the event to the *existing* ones. You may use [delegated event approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to fix the problem:

```
$("#table").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', "#tbl-body tr td", function(e) { 
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.