# Set td checked attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that has multiple rows and each row has a checkbox:

```
<tr id="${user_id}" class="SearchAccount" style="height: 40px;">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>20/12/2013</td>
    <td>
        <div class="itoggle">
            <input type="checkbox" name='${user_id}' value="member" class="editteamtextbox" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="${user_id}" class="SearchAccount" style="height: 40px;">
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Jones</td>
    <td>20/12/2013</td>
    <td>div class="itoggle">
        <input type="checkbox" name='${user_id}' value="member" class="editteamtextbox" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am having a problem setting the "checked" when the checkbox is changed:
I do this with the following code:

```
$('.editteamtextbox').iToggle({
     easing: 'easeOutExpo',
     keepLabel: true,
     speed: 200,
     onClickOn: function () {
         $(this).closest('input').prop('checked', 'checked');
     },
     onClickOff: function () {
         $(this).closest('input').prop('checked', 'false');
     }
 });
```

Comment: What you are looking for is may be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296850/click-table-rows-to-select-checkbox-using-jquery

Comment: Just curious, have you tried `$(this).prop('checked', true/false)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to every you click on td tag it check your radio, you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('td .itoggle').click(function(){
        if($(this).children("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked')){
            $(this).children("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
        }
        else{
            $(this).children("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);        
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think OP is use [iToggle](http://labs.engageinteractive.co.uk/itoggle/) plugin and having problem there