# How do I select table row using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to to select a table row using JQuery, but it seems not to fire the .selected event.  I have put the code on JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/3tevxmps/1/

I would like a table row selected when the mouse is clicked and change row colour and display an alert message with the selected row information.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
    $("td").click(function () {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass("selected");

    });
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine.. What is the problem with it?

Comment: [Like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296850/click-table-rows-to-select-checkbox-using-jquery)

Comment: You need to select the entire row, right ??

Comment: Yes, but also display an alert box where it would should the selected row values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this: [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/enginustun/3tevxmps/7/)

you can add class each td like: "p" for product, "i" for inf Rate, "n" for note, and get in click event.

**js changes:**

```
$("tbody tr").click(function () {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var product = $('.p',this).html();
    var infRate =$('.i',this).html();
    var note =$('.n',this).html();
    alert(product +','+ infRate+','+ note);
});
```

**css changes:**

```
table.formatHTML5 tr.selected {
    background-color: #e92929 !important;
    color:#fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: That's great, but any idea how to get the selected row field values and display in an alert message box?

Comment: That is perfect, thank you very much for your help it is great learning from you guys!Please Vote this

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the event on the table row (tr) and then change color of each table cell (td)

```
$("tr").click(function () {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).find("td").addClass("selected");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You tr is inside tbody so you have to use something like this

```
$("#myTable tbody tr").live('click', function (event)
    {
           //adding class
           //removing class
    });
```

**Note:** `live` may not support in latest version of jquery . use `ON` accordingly

**Working fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/550nq015/

Comment: so why than suggesting a method (`.live()`) that is long-time deprecated?

Comment: roko just in case if some one using jquery 1.8.3 and below . for 1.8.3 plus i suggested to use `ON` in place of `live`

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code.. Here is my solution.

First, the clickable element is a td element. So in JQuery function you need to ask the parent of this element. To do that you can do with this code.

```
$("td").click(function () {
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');

        });
```

It will add a class to your parent tr element from td that you click. I noticed the css you provide is only work with td element. So I write new rule for selected row element.

```
table.formatHTML5 tr.selected{
            background-color: #e92929 !important;
            vertical-align: middle !important;
            height: 4em;  
        }
```

otherwise, you can also add onClick html event for each tr elements displayed in the table.

Hope this answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

the Shortest way:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

    tr.selected {
        background-color: #e92929 !important;
        color: #fff;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 1.5em;
    }

</style>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".table > tbody > tr").click(function (e) {
   $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```