# Select Table Row w/ Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this table structure:

```
<div class="producttable">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>Product</th><th>SKU</th></tr>
<tr><td>Product1</td><td>SKU1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Product2</td><td>SKU2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I'm attempting to make an entire row clickable, but am not able to get the right jquery selector.  I've tried:

```
$(".producttable tr").click....
```

The only selector that seems to work is:

```
$(".producttable").click
```

- but this selects the entire table.  Any advice on how to get the row?

Comment: You can use this solution if you want to subscribe on dynamic quantity of <tr> in your table - $(".producttable").on('click', 'tr', function(){....});

Comment: `$(".producttable tr").on("click", function(){ console.log("clicked"); });` Works just fine. Check your browser's console tab for errors; most likely error would be `$ is not defined` (haven't included jQuery *before* the code in question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select table row using Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198895/how-do-i-select-table-row-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$(".producttable table tr")
```

Just one more tip, the click event is fired from the *td* element, an example to add an active class to the row [here](http://codepen.io/feardarkness/pen/aJNJwW)

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly and what I thought would work.  Seems my real issues is that the table is returned from another jquery call and not selectable.

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/o7qt4zuc/10/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.producttable tr').on('click', function(e) {
    var row = $(this);
    row.css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

You should really check if the event bubling isn't getting you. The click occurs in the TUDO first and then it is bubled up to the TR. This may be a catch.

Other thing to be aware is the actions that you are performing on the selected element. Can you edit the question with the full function body?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***traversing***, e.g.:

```
    $(".producttable").find("tr").click(function(){
        alert("you selected a table row!");
    });
```

See here for jQuery traversing methods:
https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/