# change color of selected rows in bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how to change the colour of checked/selected rows in bootstrap table, when selected row of a table colour that specific row should be changed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.checkall').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        // Test to see if it is checked
        checked = $this.prop('checked'),
        //Find all the checkboxes
        cbs = $this.closest('table').children('tbody').find('.checkbox');
    // Check or Uncheck them.
    cbs.prop('checked', checked);
    //toggle the selected class to all the trs
    cbs.closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', checked);
 });

 });
```

Comment: What is not working as expected in your code?

Comment: post your HTML table structure too.. `(cbs.prop('checked', checked)) ? cbs.closest('tr').addClass('bgClass') : else do whatever`

Comment: i need css to change color

Comment: `tr.bgSelectedRow { background: #ccc}` add this class bgSelectedRow to the selected `tr`

Comment: `cbs.parent().closest('tr').toggleClass('selected');`  add it in your last of click function and add this style in style tag `.selected {
   background:#ccc;
 }`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rxsrmqrm/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight the table row on checkbox checked than we can use an if condition with is(":checked"), if yes than we find the closest tr element using .closest() and than we add class to it using addClass()

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) { //If the checkbox is checked
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row"); 
    //Add class on checkbox checked
} else {
    $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
    //Remove class on checkbox uncheck
}
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FbHAV/2/)

Source: [Mr.Alien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296850/click-table-rows-to-select-checkbox-using-jquery)