# Making parent div clickable for a checkbox + label with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got the following HTML

```
<div class="ccm-custom-style-container ccm-custom-style-intro4-308 image-caption">
    <input checked="true" type="checkbox">
    <label for="D_1"><span></span><p>whitepaper is geselecteerd</p></label>
        <h4>header</h4>
        <p>text</p>
</div>
```

I use 2 scripts with this code:
the first script toggles the html text between `<label>` and `</label>` depending if the checkbox is checked or not:

```
  $('input').change(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $(this).('label').html('<span></span>whitepaper is geselecteerd');
} else {
  $(this).('label').html('<span></span>whitepaper niet geselecteerd');
}});
```

The second script toggles the class of the parent div:

```
  $('input').change(function () {           
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('ccm-custom-style-intro4-308',checked);
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('ccm-custom-style-intro4-309',!checked);});
```

This all works perfectly, but now i want to enable users to click the entire div to toggle the checkbox from checked to unchecked and back. I'm no Jquery-god so i was wondering: How would i be able to do this so it will all work together?

Comment: You cannot have `<p>` inside `<label>` and browsers will expel it outside. What's the reason you are putting `<span></span>`. The `<span></span>` here doesn't have any value.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296850/click-table-rows-to-select-checkbox-using-jquery

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks for your comment. the <p> seems to work properly in Chrome. I will test it in other browsers too. The <span> is used to show an image in .css ( input[type="checkbox"] + label span {} )

Answer (score 0):

you can make a click event for div and `.trigger('change');` the input

```
$('.ccm-custom-style-container').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('input').trigger('change');
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/88seoyve/5/)

Comment: Hi Mohammed, 

Thanks for your comment. I changed the trigger to .trigger('click') and it seemed to work. Although i can't click the label anymore. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: @Lex if your label no longer work .. just use  in its click    function(e){e.stopPropagation()}