# Jquery - not selecting td based on th class

Tags: jquery

I use following jQuery to select a checkbox in first column when we click on a row, except when we click on last cell in a row.

```
tableid.on('click', 'tbody td:not(td:last-child)', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
});
```

I added `noselecting` class to thead>th. Now like I skipped last cell using `:not(td:last-child')` how can I skip td from the on click on columns thead>th with class `noselecting`?

Comment: I think you are trying to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296850/click-table-rows-to-select-checkbox-using-jquery)?

Comment: I am trying to select a tbody>td if thead>th.noselecting is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test it withing the click handler using the index

```js
var tableid = $('#mytable');
tableid.on('click', 'tbody td:not(td:last-child)', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    index = $this.index();
  if (!$this.closest('table').find('th').eq(index).hasClass('noselecting')) {
    $this.parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.noselecting {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th class="noselecting">2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th class="noselecting">5</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```